# How to make grid master "accept" gone hosts?

Tags: gridengine

With `gridengine-master` 6.2u5-7.3 (Ubuntu Trusty), our `/var/lib/gridengine/spool/qmaster/messages` gets constantly filled with:

```
12/07/2016 04:11:43|worker|tools-grid-master|E|got load report of unknown exec host "tools-exec-1204.eqiad.wmflabs"
```

(`tools-exec-1204.eqiad.wmflabs` is a host that no longer exists.)

How can I convince the grid master to "move on", i. e. "accept" that it did receive a load report from an unknown host, or "delete" the load report from its inbox?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was that the host had been shut down and removed from DNS, but was still referenced in `host_aliases`.  Removing the entry for the host from `host_aliases` and restarting the grid master to reread `host_aliases` (`service gridengine-master restart`) caused the errors to stop.